# RabbitMq exchange performance

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message-queue, messagebroker

Is it better regarding performance to create multiple exchanges? For instance, if I have multiple file types like zip, json, xml,…

1. Is it better to create one file exchange (Topic exchange), which accepts all files and map them to the right queues. Here, my concern is that if I get many zip files and the messages accumulate at the file exchange less frequently messages are processed late.
2. Or to create one exchange per file type (Zip exchange, Json exchange, Xml exchange).

How, does an exchange processes messages? Is there only one process, which handles the mapping between the exchange and the queues or are the multiple processes, which do the mapping in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ stores the messages to the queues, the exchanges don't store the messages.
Multiple queues can work in parallel.

To have a good performance you have to use different queues and avoid too many bindings between exchanges and queues.

Comment: But, as far as I understand messages get routed from the exchange to the different queues, depended on the routing. If I send a lot of messages to one exchange, I guess it can happen that the messages don't get processed/routed immediately from the exchange to the right queue. Thus, they will be delivered to the queue with a delay?

Comment: The routing is fast, the performance problems are always related to the queues that handle the messages